# Make N copies of JS object and make changes in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    headerName: 'Make',
    field: 'make',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Model',
    field: 'model',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Price',
    field: 'price',
  },
]
```

I need to do a complex of modifications:

1) Create a new array with N copies of start array, for example 2:

```
[
  {
    headerName: 'Make',
    field: 'make',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Model',
    field: 'model',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Price',
    field: 'price',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Make',
    field: 'make',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Model',
    field: 'model',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Price',
    field: 'price',
  },
]
```

2) Set the index for each object in the field field

```
[
  {
    headerName: 'Make',
    field: 'make0',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Model',
    field: 'model0',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Price',
    field: 'price0',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Make',
    field: 'make1',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Model',
    field: 'model1',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Price',
    field: 'price1',
  }
]
```

How to implement this function?

PS. I have own option of this function, but it is not working correctly:

```js
export const formatColumns = (columns, pageCount) => {
  let formatArray = []

  for (let i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
    let copy = columns.slice(0)

    formatArray = [...formatArray, ...copy.map(item => (item.field = item.field + i))]
  }
  console.log(formatArray)
}
```

```js
const columns = [
  {
    headerName: 'Make',
    field: 'make',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Model',
    field: 'model',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Price',
    field: 'price',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Make',
    field: 'make',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Model',
    field: 'model',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Price',
    field: 'price',
  },
]

const formatColumns = (columns, pageCount) => {
  let formatArray = []

  for (let i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
    let copy = columns.slice(0)

    formatArray = [...formatArray, ...copy.map(item => (item.field = item.field + i))]
  }
  console.log(formatArray)
}

formatColumns(columns, 2);
```

The result of this function is:

```
0: "make0"
1: "model0"
2: "price0"
3: "make01"
4: "model01"
5: "price01"
6: "make012"
7: "model012"
8: "price012"
9: "make0123"
10: "model0123"
11: "price0123"
12: "make01234"
13: "model01234"
14: "price01234"
15: "make012345"
16: "model012345"
17: "price012345"
```

What am I doing wrong, and how should I fix it?

Comment: Your data structure does not make a lot of sense to me, instead of postfixing your variable names with numbers, you should use an array or array of arrays (I would use an array of nested objects...).

Comment: @jeroen, i use ag grid column system, where value of field 'field' is link for data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating additional copies of the objects with `Array.from`, take the current index in the mapper function, and append it to the `field` value of every object:

```js
const copies = 3;

const arr = [{
    headerName: 'Make',
    field: 'make',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Model',
    field: 'model',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Price',
    field: 'price',
  },
];

const output = Array.from(
  { length: copies },
  (_, i) => arr.map(
    ({ field, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, field: field + i })
  )
)
  .flat()
console.log(output);
```

Or, if you want to stick with your `for` loop:

```js
const copies = 3;

const arr = [{
    headerName: 'Make',
    field: 'make',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Model',
    field: 'model',
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Price',
    field: 'price',
  },
];

let output = [];

for (let i = 0; i < copies; i++) {
  const copy = arr.slice().map(({ field, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, field: field + i }));
  output = [...output, ...copy]
}
console.log(output);
```

A problem with your original code is that when you do

```
let copy = columns.slice(0)
...copy.map(item => (item.field = item.field + i))
```

you're not copying the objects - `.slice` only creates a shallow copy of the array, and then inside the `.map`, you mutate the existing objects, without copying them (and then you return the result of the `item.field + i` expression, which isn't desirable).

You need to fully copy the object inside the `.map` callback instead, and return a new object with an altered `field`.

Comment: First solution is a very neat combination of operations.